# Looping through each tab in a JQueryUI Tab Control and building an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, tabs

Take the following bog standard JQuery UI markup:

```
<div id="Tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Home">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ContactUs">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="Home">
    <p>Static Content bla bla bla</p>
  </div>
  <div id="About">
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="ContactUs">
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently we build an array of objects to represent each tab - this allows us to easily add additional properties to each tab relevant to our own application. For Example:

```
var Tabs = [];

$(function () {
    //#### Ready tabs and add event handles
    $("#Tabs").tabs();

    AddTab(0, "Home", "Welcome");
    AddTab(1, "About", "About");
    AddTab(2, "ContactUs", "Contact us");
});

function AddTab(Index, ID, Caption) {
    var Tab = {
        "Index": 0,
        "ID": ID,
        "Caption": Caption,
        "Version": 1,
        "Loaded": false
    };
    Tabs.push(Tab);
}
```

This is clumsy and requires me to retype stuff in js that could no doubt be gathered automatically by looping through the JQuery tab object / DOM.

So, I tried the following:

```
$('#Tabs .ui-tabs-nav a').each(function () {
    AddTab(0, $(this).html(), $(this).attr('href'))
});
```

This works great for getting the tabs Caption & ID - however, I don't see how I can get the tabs zero-based index - How can I get the tabs zero based index in my each() loop above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .index(). Use .parent() to get the `<li>` element and use .index() to get index of that element

```
 AddTab($(this).parent().index(), $(this).html(), $(this).attr('href'))
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.each` will give you the index as first argument of callback

```
$('#Tabs .ui-tabs-nav a').each(function (index, element) {
    AddTab(index, $(this).html(), $(this).attr('href'))
    /*or  using element argument*/
     AddTab(index, $(element).html(), element.href)
});
```

[**See .each() docs**](http://api.jquery.com/each/)